# Extract partial value using JMeter JSON Extractor

Tags: json, parsing, jmeter

I parse json to variable using jmeter, and I can only parse to a certain point, in this JSON I would like to parse the value of `tt_cid`, that is located under `nurl` parameter in JSON , How to parse this value? (I managed to parse the entire `nurl` but not inside it).

2. How to move more than one variable in the same JSON extractor?

I put the JSON PIC and the extractor that I used to parse `nurl`, I would like to parse `tt_cid` that is inside `nurl` field.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a `Regular Expression Extractor` after your JSON Extractor that will use the variable created by the JSON Extractor.

You need to select `JMeter Variable` radio button with `nurl` value after JSON Extractor:

Regex will be:

> &tt_cid(\W+)

[image]

Comment: And If I want to parse more than 1 variable, is there a way to use regex with multiple variables and regular expression for example 20 fields to extract?

Comment: You need 20 regular expressions to get 20 variables

Comment: you mean to add 20 regex? I can not do it in the same one and separate by comma or something? the test will be http request and than 20 regex>? it will be very long in the UI

Comment: Theoretically you can but with overhead, in UI you can fold the hierarchy